# What does becoming a canine good citizen allow me to do with my dog?

Tags: dogs, training, legal

My dog is taking a manners class which I hope will end with him becoming a [canine good citizen](https://www.akc.org/dogowner/training/canine_good_citizen/). What does this designation enable me to do with my dog?  Are there public places that don't allow dogs, but will allow dogs that are canine good citizens?  Are there places where leash laws don't apply to canine good citizens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't seem to have any real benefit unless you are a breeder or want to use your dog for special purposes.  While many states have passed "resolutions" about it, this basically just means that the American Kennel Club has spent enough money on politicians to be able to buy a "resolution" which is just the state legislature saying "we like this".  I couldn't find anything about any special privileges.  It is just a basic level of dog training that may be used by some organizations as a precursor to additional training or participating in some programs.

If anything, the program places additional constraints on you as an owner since your responsibilities for the certification are higher than what would otherwise be required.

Comment: Don't forget you get to put more letters after your dog's name! Practically though, I believe it also helps if you are trying to get therapy dog certification (so you can visit hosptials and such).

Comment: Yeah. That is one of the programs it is sometimes a precursor to.